# Regular expression - How to match only character after number, without including number in match pattern

Tags: java, regex

I want to determine a regular expression, but came up with only the below

```
Expression = ^[£]*|(,)|[0-9]p$

Test String  = £4dj,gs,dl"34p
```

Issue: In my test string "4p" is coming as a match (which is near to my expection), but I want only "p" to be highlighted/matched, as I want to do a replace of p (and not the number),

**Goal**: replace p only if it comes after a number, without touching the number

```
Test String  = ship  
p in ship is not a match, which is valid for my scenario.
```

https://regex101.com/
[image]

Comment: try `(?<=[0-9])[A-Za-z]` or `(?<=[0-9])\w`

Comment: Like `(?<=[0-9])p` ? To get the matches in the screenshot `[£,]|(?<=[0-9])p` https://regex101.com/r/lXC451/1

Comment: Do you mean ^[£]*|(,)|(?<=[0-9])p$  ? Please note that the rest of the rules should not be impacted. i.e. start with £ , match all commas. Edit: I think this works, it was screen refresh issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `^[£]*` matches optional repetitions of £ at the start of the string, and can also match an empty string.

If you only want to match the character to be replaced, you don't need the capture group around the single quote.

Your pattern, with the anchors:

```
^£|,|(?<=[0-9])p$
```

- `^£` Match a pound sign at the start of the string
- `|` Or
- `,` Match a comma
- `|` Or
- `(?<=[0-9])p$` Match a `p` char at the end of the string asserting a digit to the left

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5sezMU/1)

Without the anchors to match all occurrences, you can combine the comma and pound sign in a character class.

```
[£,]|(?<=[0-9])p
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J9kzbC/1)